# How to add a not null constraint to an already existing column with null values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen a similar question on stackexchange, but it's answer did not give me the correct results.

For demonstration purposes, I have a simple table `PURCHASES` with columns `PURCHASE_NUM`, `PURCHASE_DATE`, `CUSTOMER_ID.`  I want to enforce a not null constraint on the `CUSTOMER_ID` table.  I tried the following:

```
ALTER TABLE PURCHASES MODIFY CUSTOMER_ID char NOT NULL;
```

That syntax is fine, but then I insert with the following: `INSERT INTO PURCHASES VALUES (333, NULL, NULL);` and the tuple is added without issue.  Why is the constraint not being enforced?  Would having NULL values already in that column before adding the constraint affect things?

Thanks

*edit* `DESCRIBE PURCHASES;` says the following for the column of interest:

```
Field, Type, Null, Key, Default, Extra
CUSTOMER_ID, char(5), YES, , NULL,
```

Comment: s/PURCHASE_ID/CUSTOMER_ID/ in your ALTER statement?

Comment: Woops, just a typo when typing the question.  Fixed.

Comment: Show us what `DESCRIBE PURCHASES;` says.

Comment: Seems to work just fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9b56/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ALTER` command didn't work, the `Null` column still says `YES`.  Your `ALTER` command syntax looks just fine, it should have worked.  Check your typing and try again.

Is your customer ID really just a char?

Comment: Yup, char(5).  Not my original database and I can't make that change right now.  I will try again... Would having NULL values already in the data make it not work?

Comment: No, it should still work.  `NULL` char values seem to be converted to the empty string as part of the `ALTER`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to change to

```
ALTER TABLE PURCHASES MODIFY  CUSTOMER_ID char NOT NULL;
```

Comment: According to the documentation, a `DEFAULT` must be set.

Comment: I think, he knows how it works. The problem is, he has a mistake of column in alter table ( CUSTOMER_ID and CUSTOMER_ID).

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, data entry into a `NOT NULL` column that has no explicit `DEFAULT` clause will set the column to `NULL`. Thus, you should `ALTER` your column to contain a `DEFAULT`. From 4.0 documentation:

> Implicit defaults are defined as follows:
>
> For numeric types, the default is `0`, with the exception that for integer or floating-point types declared with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute, the default is the next value in the sequence.
>
> For date and time types other than `TIMESTAMP`, the default is the appropriate “zero” value for the type. For the first `TIMESTAMP` column in a table, the default value is the current date and time. See Section 10.3, “Date and Time Types”.
>
> For string types other than `ENUM`, the default value is the empty string. For ENUM, the default is the first enumeration value.

Comment: This behavior changed as of 5.0.2.

Comment: The `DESCRIBE PURCHASES` shows the `ALTER` didn't take.  So I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @KeithRandall The way I'm reading the 5.0 manual, it sounds like `DEFAULT NULL` is explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you've got to notice that you're trying to do something **ilogic**: Trying to make a column with null values NOT NULL.

I guess that what you're trying to say is *"i need that a column created after the creation of the table becomes NOT NULL".* But first of all, you need to make all NULL values from that newly-created column become something else that is not null. Check the example below:

*adds a new column to an already existent table

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN salary DECIMAL(15, 2);
```

*updates all values from the newly-created column to something else - 0

```
UPDATE users
SET salary = 0
WHERE salary IS NULL;
```

*makes the column NOT NULL

```
ALTER TABLE users
MODIFY salary DECIMAL(15, 2)
NOT NULL;
```